# Add margin to pdf page

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a pdf book that is not showing up completely. I have attached a screenshot of acrobat's print preview showing what the issue is. As you can see there is more conentent on the left of the page that is not showing up.

[image: PDF book with more content to the left]

I have tried:
Changing the paper size
Changing the dimensions to "fit"
Opening in Google docs
Opening in mac's preview
Opening in Google Books.

Any ideas of what I can try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204307/adding-a-margin-to-pdf-pages-with-pypdf2/77302887#77302887

Answer (score 14):

As a late answer and when using Linux, one can use the command line tool "pdfjam".

## Add margins to pages

Desired result: remove 0.5 cm from top and bottom of page, add 2 cm to right margin. Keep page size (important)

```
pdfjam --fitpaper true --trim "0cm 0.5cm -2cm 0.5cm" input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

- Negative numbers in the trim-argument means "add", while a positive means "remove".
- The four numbers within the trim-arguments relates to the left, bottom, right and top margin
- If fitpaper is set to false the trim will move the content around the page and not resize the page.
- You can add "--frame true" to see what's going on.

## Move content to the left

Desired result: make right margin 1 cm larger and left margin 1 cm smaller

```
pdfjam --offset "-1cm 0cm" input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

The command below will move the content of the page 1 cm from right to left.

## pdfjam and documentation

Documentation about pdfjam can be found here: http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam

The combination of `pdfinfo`, `pdftk` and `pdfjam` can be used to modify PDFs quickly on a more advanced level.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would check if [PDF page boxes](http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/page-boxes) are correct. Especially if document looks fine in viewer but offset in print preview.

The issue might be caused by any of the boxes defined so they are outside of MediaBox.

Another approach to try is to impose this document onto other document with some offset. Others recommend Multivalent and Ghostscript for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the PDF it is hard to determine the exact reason for what you're seeing, but often the reason is that the CropBox is smaller than the MediaBox. The MediaBox is the size of the physical page and the CropBox is the area of the page that is viewed or printed. If no CropBox is specified then its value is inherited from the MediaBox.

You can programmatically get the page box dimensions and also set them using my companies free PDF SDK. It's an ActiveX for Windows and it is called [Debenu Quick PDF Library Lite](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library-lite/).

Upload the PDF and share a link if the page box dimensions do not solve the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I had to change the page size of the file (Printing to pdf on a larger paper didnt work)

Steps to get it down:

1. Open Adobe Acrobat Plus
2. Click on "tools"
3. Click on "Crop" (which is under the "Page" section)
4. Double click anywhere on the pdf
5. Under "Change page size" make it larger then what it is
6. apply to all!

That's it!