# Adding a margin to pdf pages with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, printing, formatting, margin

I am creating a python script that can modify a pdf file to be printed in book sections. As there is no such functionality in the ubuntu printing settings.

PyPDF2 is a wonderful tool with which I have been able to do everything I wanted except adding a margin.

For example consider this book.
http://www.edwardothorp.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/beatthemarket.pdf
It requires some margins so that there is some room for binding them in a book.
I have found how to shift the content a few pixels, but the size of the "canvas" doesn't change so some content is cut off.

I am able to adjust the "page size" with PyPDF2 by changing the mediabox size but I an only crop the pages, I cannot increase their size.
And to add margins, I have to increase the size. 
I also can't shrink the content, because then for some reason the page size shrinks with it.

Here is the script if you want to print a book.
http://pastebin.com/LGYhKYu1
Of course, it only works with pdfs with already some margins so you only need to shift the content.

I would be most grateful if someone could point out how to add margins to a pdf with PyPDF2 , I must be overlooking something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

It seems there is no dedicated method, but you can create an empty page of the desired size, then merge your content with the empty page

```
page = PageObject.createBlankPage(
        yourPage.mediaBox.getWidth () + 2 * margin,  
        yourPage.mediaBox.getHeight() + 2 * margin)
page.mergeScaledTranslatedPage( yourPage, scale, leftMargin, bottomMargin)    
...
output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(page)
```

Answer (score 1):

I myself was trying to figure out this. My objective was to crop a B5 page content and fit in A4 for booklet

```
bind_margin = 60
for pnum in tqdm(range(numpage)):
    page = inpdf.getPage(pnum)

    # Trim margins from right and left
    page.trimBox.lowerLeft = tuple([a+b for a, b in zip(page.trimBox.lowerLeft, (50, 0))])
    page.trimBox.upperRight = tuple([a-b for a, b in zip(page.trimBox.upperRight, (50, 0))])
    page.cropBox.lowerLeft = tuple([a+b for a, b in zip(page.cropBox.lowerLeft, (50, 0))])
    page.cropBox.upperRight = tuple([a-b for a, b in zip(page.cropBox.upperRight, (50, 0))])

    # create empty A4 size page
    emptyPage = pdf.PageObject.createBlankPage(width=tarw, height=tarh)
    margin_available = tarw + page.mediaBox.lowerLeft[0] - page.mediaBox.upperRight[0]

    if pnum%2==0:
            tx = bind_margin
    else:
            tx = margin_available - bind_margin

    emptyPage.mergeTranslatedPage(page, tx, 180)

    outpdf.addPage(emptyPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume for instance you say ODD pages shall have **more margin on the left side** than on the right side, and EVEN pages shall have **more margin on the right** side than on the left side. I used *primary variable* for bigger side margin and *secondary variable* for regular side margin, top and bottom margins for to and bottom. I used this script to prepare pdf for book hardcover printing, **where book starts with odd page on the right hand side (so left margin is bigger than right)** and opposite goes for even pages.

```
import argparse
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def to_points(x):
    return x * 72 if measure == "inch" else x * 28.8

def add_margins(input_pdf, output_pdf, primary=0, secondary=0, top=0, bottom=0):
    with open(input_pdf, 'rb') as f:
        reader = PdfReader(f)
        writer = PdfWriter()

        for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
            i = i + 1

            if i % 2 == 0:
                page.mediabox.lower_left = (float(page.mediabox.lower_left[0]) - secondary, float(page.mediabox.lower_left[1]) - bottom)
                page.mediabox.lower_right = (float(page.mediabox.lower_right[0]) + primary, float(page.mediabox.lower_right[1]) - bottom)
                page.mediabox.upper_left = (float(page.mediabox.upper_left[0]) - secondary, float(page.mediabox.upper_left[1]) + top)
                page.mediabox.upper_right = (float(page.mediabox.upper_right[0]) + primary, float(page.mediabox.upper_right[1]) + top)
            else:
                page.mediabox.lower_left = (float(page.mediabox.lower_left[0]) - primary, float(page.mediabox.lower_left[1]) - bottom)
                page.mediabox.lower_right = (float(page.mediabox.lower_right[0]) + secondary, float(page.mediabox.lower_right[1]) - bottom)
                page.mediabox.upper_left = (float(page.mediabox.upper_left[0]) - primary, float(page.mediabox.upper_left[1]) + top)
                page.mediabox.upper_right = (float(page.mediabox.upper_right[0]) + secondary, float(page.mediabox.upper_right[1]) + top)

            writer.add_page(page)

        with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as out:
            writer.write(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Add margins to a PDF file.")
    parser.add_argument('input_pdf', type=str, help="Input PDF file path")
    parser.add_argument('output_pdf', type=str, help="Output PDF file path")
    parser.add_argument('--side_p', type=float, default=0, help="Margin of primary side")
    parser.add_argument('--side_s', type=float, default=0, help="Margin of secondary side")
    parser.add_argument('--top', type=float, default=0, help="Top margin")
    parser.add_argument('--bottom', type=float, default=0, help="Bottom margin")
    parser.add_argument('--measure', type=str, default=0, help="cm or inch")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    measure = args.measure

    add_margins(
        args.input_pdf,
        args.output_pdf,
        to_points(args.side_p),
        to_points(args.side_s),
        to_points(args.top),
        to_points(args.bottom)
    )
```

Launch in cmd: `python add-margings-pdf.py linear-algebra-printing.pdf out-linear-algebra-printing.pdf --side_p 0.75 --side_s 0.5 --top 0.5 --bottom 0.5 --measure inch`

Comment: took time to understand how library actually increases page in X and Y directions. For instance I want to increase odd page in left side, so I substract primary from lower_left X and upper_left X to create a space, so white area of pdf grows in negative direction. The odd/even page Y works like: it starts on the bottom, I substract from lower_left Y and lower_right Y to make it grow to negative direction.